# Is there any way to recover objects matching several criterias (not necessairly ID)?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working on a project that is using hibernate.
We have a database and now I would like to query it.

In the ideal case, I know I am able to recover an object by its ID or by using Hibernate's query language. But it would be optimal to me if there was a method to which I send an object with the attributes I want to be used as a filter and get back all the objects in that table that match these criterias.
For instance

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setName("Junior");
p.setAge(10);
session.Load(Person.class, p); //this would return all "junior" with age = 10
```

I imagine Hibernate would provide a similar functionality. Does it? Which method should I use?

Thanks,
Oscar

EDIT:
@nIKUNJ indicated me to Criteria, which would be something very similar to what I need.
The problem is: I would like to have a DatabaseManager class, which would handle the save, load, etc features.
For instance, my load would look like this:

```
public <T extends Serializable> List<T> load(T filters, Class<T> type)
{
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        List<T> searchResult;
        session.beginTransaction(); 

        searchResult = ((List<T>)session.get(type, filters)); //assuming the method
                                                 //I asked for in the question exists


        return searchResult;
}
```

This way, I would be able to send almost any object to this method and the method would query the database and return me a List of objects that match the criteria.

Do you have any idea how I could mimic this behavior that using the Criteria class?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Hibernate [Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) can help you.

You can use one `parameter` class having three attributes: `name, type and value`. `Name` will be name of  you column, `type` will be equals, less then, greater then etc. condition types, and `value` will be  value for that condition.
For example, `name="person.age", type = greater equal, value=18`. Create a utility method that converts these parameters into criteria objects.

Now, create a method like this:

```
public <T extends Serializable> List<T> load(List<Parameter> params, Class<T> type)
{
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        List<T> searchResult;
        session.beginTransaction(); 
        Criteria criteria = createCriteriaFromParams(params);    
        searchResult = criteria.list();  

        return searchResult;
}
```

This is very simple scenario. You can create some complex criteria by adding some extra attributes in parameter list.

Comment: This would be exactly what I wanted. A question came to my mind, I will update the current question in order to keep it up to date. Thanks :)

Comment: I think this will help me. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: For completion, I found this tutorial which teaches to use a business object to create the Criteria object, without the params parameter :) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Hibernate/CriteriaQBEQueryByExampleAdvancedCriteria.htm